# "TypeError posts.map is not a function" while using getServerSideProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am following a Next.Js tutorial about server-side rendering. The solution works if I add the fetch in the same `index.js` file.

`/pages/posts/index.js`:

```
    export default function index({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Posts API</h2>
      <ul>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  const posts = await res.json();
  console.log(posts);
  return { props: { posts } };
}
```

However, when I break the code in a component like this

file: `/pages/posts/index.js`

```
import { userGetPosts } from '../lib/posts';



export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const posts = await userGetPosts();
  //const data =   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( posts))
  console.log(posts);
  return { props: { posts } };
}

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      
      <section className={`${utilStyles.headingMd} ${utilStyles.padding1px}`}>
        <h2 className={utilStyles.headingLg}>Blog</h2>
        <ul>
          {/* ENABLING THIS throws error */}
        {/* {posts.map((post) => {
          return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
        })} */}
      </ul>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

`../lib/posts.js`

```
export async  function userGetPosts (){
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  {/* Need to convert to text else the index.js get array of objects*/}
  const posts = await res.text();
  //console.log(posts);
  return { props: { posts } };
};
```

The `console.log(posts)` shows that the response is received but when I try and do `posts.map`, I get an error on the browser -
`TypeError posts.map is not a function`

I tried using `JSON.parse(posts)` because, from the component, I am passing as text, but that does not help.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: ISSUE FIXED**.

Thanks @Youssouf Oumar - Your comment helped find the issue.
I was following this official tutorial on Next.js website - https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/getstaticprops-details

The primary issue was that
in my `index.js`, where I was calling the function `userGetPosts()` as

```
export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const posts = await userGetPosts();
  console.log(posts);
  **return { props: { posts } };** ***<---- THIS WAS THE ISSUE***
}
```

I changed the code to

```
export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const posts = await userGetPosts();
  console.log(posts);
  **return posts;**
}
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? I did not find any solution, all posts are very generic and none of them talk about calling them from component. If you are downvoting then please mention the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the return type of `userGetPosts` as below, so `getServerSideProps` returns `{ props: { posts } }` and not `{ props: { posts: { props: { posts } } } }`

```js
export async  function userGetPosts (){
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  const posts = await res.text();
  return posts;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try By Writing This Code

Code Link With Excution

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-wright-xf4ms6

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Index({ posts  }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(posts);
  }, [posts]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Posts API Is There</h2>
      <ul>
        {posts &&
          posts.length > 0 &&
          posts.map((post) => {
            return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
          })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  console.log("Get Server Side Props Running");
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const posts = await res.json();
  console.log(posts);
  return { props: { posts } };
}
```

First Make Sure You Are Getting Response

Then Return in JSON Format

And check wheter you are getting data in props

If there is No Any Rendring Then There is No Data inside Post

If this work for then please upvote and correct it worked for you

Comment: There is data already present and I can log in console - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. However, I did try your advice and although the posts is getting printed in logs,  I see that results of the call is not available when the page is rendererd - {posts.length>1?'y':'n'} This prints "n".

Comment: Why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: actualy first get statisc props was not rendring 
then you are returning a text not an object

Comment: Please see my issue above. This approach already works. The issue is when I move this to a separate file.    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");    Then it stops working.

Comment: **getServerSidePros** only work in main/index/route JS page if folder structure is page then **index.js** else if  **page.js**